# No route matches [PUT]. How to correctly route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have this code for my _form.html.haml:

```
= form_tag edit_work_flows_path, :method=> 'put' do |f|
  -@all_configurations.each do |config|
    -if config.configuration_key == 'DUPLICATE_CLAIM_WI_MANAGER'
      =hidden_field_tag "config_ids[]", config.id
      .fieldset.field-group.field-group-inline.pull-left
        .field.field-text
          %label= t('workflow.duplicate_claim_manager')
```

It is giving the error that "No route matches [PUT]"

However, when I change the form_tag to `app_configurations_path` it works. But it doesn't go to the page I want. I want it to go to the edit_work_flows_path page. Here is my route:

```
    scope '/settings' do
      resource :app_configurations, only: [:edit, :update] do
        collection { get 'cover_letter_template' }
      end
      resource :work_flows, only: [:edit, :update]
    end
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what are your routes?, run this in your console: rake routes grep | work_flows

Comment: whats the output of `rake routes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No route matches [PUT]

The problem is with your `form_tag`. When you run `rake routes`, you will see like the below

```
   Prefix Verb  URI    Pattern                   Controller#Action
edit_work_flows GET   /work_flows/edit(.:format) work_flows#edit
     work_flows PATCH /work_flows(.:format)      work_flows#update
                PUT   /work_flows(.:format)      work_flows#update
```

This means the `edit_work_flows_path` can only accept `GET`, that is why you got the error. You should change `edit_work_flows_path` to `work_flows_path`. The below code should work.

```
= form_tag work_flows_path, :method=> 'put' do |f|
```